# How to insert records betweeen two orgs?

Tags: soap-api, insert

I want to do insert records between tow salesforce orgs using SOAP API . Can someone please guide me . For example i have student obj in Org A and also have student object in Org B . So when i insert records in Org A,it should reflect it in Org B . I'm particularly looking out for a sample .. Please help me to get this started.Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can Try out Salesforce-To-Salesforce  connection
[salesforce connection](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce).

It is possible for the custom object also

Comment: How do i make this with SOAP API ?

Comment: Someone has any idea please..

Comment: Can anyone share any suggestions ?